# Optimize a query that is using sub-query in where clause

Tags: sql-server

I have been trying to find a way to optimize this query by probably removing the subquery in where clause.

it currently takes 2 minutes to run this query with the where clause and 4 seconds without the where clause.

```
SELECT 
    rateString,
    currency
  FROM myTable.trades ct
  WHERE ct.id IN
      (
        SELECT top 1 id
        FROM myTable.trades tt
        WHERE tt.currency = ct.currency
        AND tt.isExecuted = 1
        AND tt.status LIKE 'executed'
        AND tt.transactionType LIKE 'sell'
        ORDER BY tt.created_at DESC
      )
ORDER BY currency, created_at DESC
```

The subquery will limit the result to the top 1 row per 
currency with some more where and order clause.

Everything is from a single table and no foreign key is involved

Comment: Welcome! We'd love to help, but there are few things that will help us answer your question. Please check out [this link](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql?cb=1)

Comment: Everything is from a single table? so cryptox.trades and myTable.trades are the same?

Comment: @EvandroMuchinski yes, typing mistake over here i guess, but everything is from a single table. let me fix that

Comment: @Forrest thanks, I am seeing a lot of suggestions in the link you provided, i am going through then as well thanks

Comment: Is `id` the primary key of `trades`?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
WITH CTE_Trades 
AS (
    SELECT  ct.rateString
    ,       ct.currency 
    ,       RowNum  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ct.currency ORDER BY ct.created_at DESC) -- try with ct.id too
    FROM    myTable.trades ct
    WHERE   ct.isExecuted = 1
    AND     ct.status = 'executed'
    AND     ct.transactionType = 'sell'
)

SELECT rateString, currency FROM CTE_Trades WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Comment: that seems to work like a charm, i am guessing what it does is create a temp table with row number and selects the row 1. ?

Comment: I would add an index on `(isExecuted, status, transactionType, currency, created_at) INCLUDE (rateString)` as well.

Comment: Not a temp table. You can use Common Table Expressions (CTE) to solve a lot of problems in SQL Server, like avoiding 'copy and paste' complex calculations or even recursive queries. Please, have a look on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Or an index on `(currency, created_at) INCLUDE (rateString) WHERE (isExecuted = 1 AND status = executed' AND transactionType = 'sell')` if you are always querying with the same parameters.

Comment: I think this could be optimized further using a WHERE EXISTS clause.  The logic states that it really only cares if there is a 'TOP 1' record.  Since it doesn't actually return anything from the sub-query, a where exists could be used instead and could potentially run quicker.  In that way, you wouldn't even need the ORDER BY(from the OP) in the sub-select or in your answer, the ROW_NUMBER() with the ORDER BY.  I haven't tested but it should return exactly the same result without the need to enumerate the table.